# Can I run Gaussian on Google Collab

Tags: gaussian

Can I use Google Collab to run my Gaussian calculations? Due to the lower specification of my system, I can not run my calculations. I have to generate .wfn file. Is there any other idea or alternative??

Comment: I do not think you can use google colab to run Gaussian calculations. From my understanding they provide access to Python, C and instances of other programming languages. However, it seems that [pyscf](https://pyscf.org/pyscf_api_docs/pyscf.tools.html) can write a .wfn file, so you can try that.